Show that $\langle 2 \rangle$ is maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$.
I was trying to show that $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]/\langle 2 \rangle$ is a field (hopefully $\mathbb{F}_2$?), but I couldn't proceed because of $2$ is on the denomenator.

Let $\alpha = (1 + \sqrt{-19})/2$. So $\alpha$ has minimal polynomial $x^2-x+5$.
Thus you have $\mathbb Z[\alpha] = \mathbb Z[x]/\langle x^2-x+5\rangle $ and thus
$$
\mathbb Z[\alpha]/\langle 2 \rangle = \mathbb Z[x]\langle x^2 - x + 5, 2\rangle = \mathbb F_2[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle.
$$
This final ring is a field since $x^2 + x + 1 \bmod 2$ is irreducible.
(Your issue is maybe you were trying to show the field was $\mathbb F_2$ and this calculation shows that it is $\mathbb F_4$.)
